# Cardinality of sets discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given $A = \{\text{Vine}, \text{Tree}, \text{Shrub}\}$; $B = \{ \text{Tree}\}$; $C = \{ \text{Vine}, \text{Moss}\}$; $D = \{\text{Red}, \text{Green}\}$; $E = \{ \text{Red} \}$

what is $A \cup B \cup C$?

Comment: Add them all to a list and eliminate duplicates.

Comment: @5space I am confused by your edit. The current $\LaTeX$ is fine, while changing the question to "What is the cardinality of $A\cup B\cup C$" changes the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\cup B\cup C=\{\text{Vine, Tree, Shrub, Tree, Vine, Moss}\}$$ How many *distinct* elements are in this set?

Comment: 4 distinct elements

Comment: There's your answer!

Comment: You are very welcome. As a side note, after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).